# How to run SVN export without the prompt of username and password

Tags: bash, svn, shell, command

Is it possible for me to do an SVN export without being prompt for the user and pass?

I give my username and pass, in the command:

```
svn export --username bavhbavh --password blahblah svn://svn.someSite.com/folder/folder2/exportFile"
```

But when running it, it still seems to ask me for a username and pass.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I do this same thing in one of my build scripts, although I also use this parameter `--non-interactive` (do no interactive prompting) and it seems to work pretty well.

So your command would look something like this:

```
svn export --username bavhbavh --password blahblah --non-interactive svn://svn.someSite.com/folder/folder2/exportFile"
```

Comment: I know the question was answered a while ago but the the --password work with SVN+SSH? I tried using the above with SVN+SSH but it still asks for my password.